# C# check for new application items when app is running

Tags: c#, refresh, auto-update, windows

I have a Reporting system that has a list of reports available for running to the user. What I want to be able to do is periodically have the application look for new reports on the SQL server and repopulate the list of reports available.

But I want to do this without locking the application, I want this to be seamless and not have the user even know it is happening.

How can I do this the most efficient way possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are looking to have a background thread perform this work, without affecting the user, and update the GUI when done.

Look into BackgroundWorker helper class.

Comment: Within a BackgroundWorker class, just to make sure, I will need to reference the main form within the class correct and make any controls that will be updated public on the main form correct?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to handle it, but public controls/variables is the easiest.  However you get to learn about Invoke - as modifying controls from the wrong thread isn't allowed.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using a background thread to do the polling. You can start a new Thread object and poll the server, sleeping after each check. If you find a change you can fetch the data and then you will need to call Invoke to update the GUI because this cannot be done on a different thread.

An alternative is to use a timer and do the check inside the Tick event, but if the check takes a long time (and it can take a long time if your server is busy or if there is a table lock) then it will block your application so I'd advise against this approach.